# rails & devise, route to home#show after login using after_sign_in_path_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

After sign-in, I want to route to my home#index, but instead, it generates a /home/:id request and hence routed to home#show.

Can someone help and see, is it possible for me to route to index after clicking the sign in button.

Thank you so much.

rake routes

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                     PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
   user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                     PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                     PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                     DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
               posts GET    /posts(.:format)               posts#index
                     POST   /posts(.:format)               posts#create
            new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)           posts#new
           edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)      posts#edit
                post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#show
                     PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                     PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                     DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#destroy
               homes GET    /homes(.:format)               homes#index
                     POST   /homes(.:format)               homes#create
            new_home GET    /homes/new(.:format)           homes#new
           edit_home GET    /homes/:id/edit(.:format)      homes#edit
                home GET    /homes/:id(.:format)           homes#show
                     PATCH  /homes/:id(.:format)           homes#update
                     PUT    /homes/:id(.:format)           homes#update
                     DELETE /homes/:id(.:format)           homes#destroy
                root GET    /                              devise/sessions#new
```

ApplicationController.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
end

protect_from_forgery with: :exception
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  home_path(resource)
end

def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
  new_user_session_path()
end 
end
```

sessions/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), :html => {:class=>'form-
signin'}) do |f| %>
  <h2 class="form-signin-heading" style="text-align:center">Log in</h2>
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true,:class=>"form-control", :type=>"email", :placeholder=>"Enter email" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", :class=>"form-control", :type=>"password", :placeholder=>"Password"%>
  <%= f.submit "Submit", :class=>"btn btn-primary btn-block" %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :posts
  resources :homes

  # routing to the login page
  devise_scope :user do
    root :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
  end
```

HomesController.rb

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController
  layout "loginpage"
  def index
  end

  def show
    @heading = "My Home"
  end

  def new
    @home = Home.new
    respond_with(@home)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @home = Home.new(home_params)
    @home.save
    respond_with(@home)
  end

  def update
    @home.update(home_params)
    respond_with(@home)
  end

  def destroy
    @home.destroy
    respond_with(@home)
  end

  private
    def set_home
      @home = Home.find(params[:id])
    end

    def home_params
      params[:home]
    end
end
```

Comment: try with `homes_path`

Comment: In applicationController? @anonymousxxx

Comment: Spend my whole morning on this..

Comment: So, without the s, it will route to show method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want after signin redirect to `homes#index` but your path on `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` method have `home_path(resource)` it will redirect to `homes#show`

look at this (your output of rake routes)

```
 ->   homes GET    /homes(.:format)               homes#index
 ->   home GET    /homes/:id(.:format)            homes#show
```

`homes_path` is named helper for path `/homes` with controller#action is `homes#index`

`home_path(id)` is named helped for path `/home/:id` with controller#action is `homes#show`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers

Try this :

If you have multiple device models

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

 private

 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.is_a?(YourDeviceModel)
        homes_path
    else
        another_path 
    end
 end
end
```

If you have single device model

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  private

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        homes_path
  end

end
```

For your question on comment

**Q: without the s, it will route to show method?**

It may not always be so, You have `resources :homes` on your `routes.rb` it can generate routing default by rails. You can read this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    home_path
  end

end
```

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'home', to: "home#index", as: :home
end
```

app/controllers/home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ActionController::Base
  def index
  end
end
```

When you specify a static route in Rails, you can just say which HTTP action you want to use, followed by the controller#action you want to forward the request to, followed by the _path name you want to set.

In your case you specified that you wanted to send the signed in user to the home_path so we set home_path via the as: param.